# Unstable wifi with Intel Wirelss 7265 on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

My Asus Zenbook UX304UA seems to have problems connecting to newer wifi standards. This first popped up when I was temporarily using my neigbhor's wifi and is now again constantly unstable when I am logged in to a semi-public company wifi. What is puzzling me is that my phone has no problems whatsoever.
Additionally, the problem gets worse when battery drops under 25%...

I have ubuntu 20.04 running and already updated to the latest BIOS version of the notebook (UX305UA.302). The output of `sudo lshw -C network` is:

```
  *-network                 
       description: wireless connection
       product: Wireless 7265
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 59
       serial: 00:21:5c:af:45:29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-81-generic firmware=29.1654887522.0 ip=192.168.183.188 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:128 memory:dfa00000-dfa01fff
```

And `ls /lib/firmware/ | grep iwlwifi-7265` yields:

```
iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode
iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-17.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-21.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-22.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-27.ucode
iwlwifi-7265D-29.ucode
```

I am connected in 2.4GHz.
I came accross [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726292/cant-connect-wifi-with-intel-ac-7265-on-ubuntu-15-10-asus-zenbook-ux305) but that didn't helped much.

**edit/update**
Output `sudo journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`:

```
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle systemd[1]: Starting Network Manager...
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759349.8229] NetworkManager (version 1.22.10) is starting... (for the first time)
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759349.8230] Read config: /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf (lib: 10-dns-resolved.conf, 20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf, >
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759349.9694] bus-manager: acquired D-Bus service "org.freedesktop.NetworkManager"
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle systemd[1]: Started Network Manager.
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759349.9868] manager[0x56248078a030]: monitoring kernel firmware directory '/lib/firmware'.
Sep 04 14:42:29 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759349.9869] monitoring ifupdown state file '/run/network/ifstate'.
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3534] hostname: hostname: using hostnamed
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3534] hostname: hostname changed from (none) to "castle"
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3537] dns-mgr[0x562480779290]: init: dns=systemd-resolved rc-manager=symlink, plugin=systemd-resolved
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3548] rfkill1: found Wi-Fi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.5/0000:02:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfk>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3550] manager[0x56248078a030]: rfkill: Wi-Fi hardware radio set enabled
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3551] manager[0x56248078a030]: rfkill: WWAN hardware radio set enabled
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3643] Loaded device plugin: NMWwanFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wwan>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3658] Loaded device plugin: NMAtmManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-adsl.>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3705] Loaded device plugin: NMTeamFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-team>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3786] Loaded device plugin: NMBluezManager (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-blu>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3814] Loaded device plugin: NMWifiFactory (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-device-plugin-wifi>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3819] manager: rfkill: Wi-Fi enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3822] manager: rfkill: WWAN enabled by radio killswitch; enabled by state file
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3825] manager: Networking is enabled by state file
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3827] dhcp-init: Using DHCP client 'internal'
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3900] settings: Loaded settings plugin: ifupdown ("/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/NetworkManager/1.22.10/libnm-settings-p>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3914] settings: Loaded settings plugin: keyfile (internal)
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3914] ifupdown: management mode: unmanaged
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3914] ifupdown:       interface-parser: parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.3914] ifupdown:       interface-parser: finished parsing file /etc/network/interfaces
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <warn>  [1630759350.4021] keyfile: 802-1x.ca-cert: Zertifikat oder Schlüsseldatei »file:///home/squirrel/.cat_installer/ca.pem« ist nich>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.4783] device (lo): carrier: link connected
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.4787] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.4794] device (wlp2s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.4800] manager: (wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.4936] device (wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.6465] modem-manager: ModemManager available
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.6488] supplicant: wpa_supplicant running
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.6493] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7818] sup-iface[0x56248079f920,wlp2s0]: supports 5 scan SSIDs
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7851] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7852] Wi-Fi P2P device controlled by interface wlp2s0 created
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7858] manager: (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): new 802.11 Wi-Fi P2P device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7879] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <warn>  [1630759350.7916] sup-iface: failed to cancel p2p connect: P2P cancel failed
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7941] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759350.7958] device (wlp2s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'm>
Sep 04 14:42:30 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <warn>  [1630759350.8073] device (wlp2s0): wifi-scan: active scanning for networks due to profiles with wifi.hidden=yes. This makes you >
Sep 04 14:42:34 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759354.4857] manager: startup complete
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8700] policy: auto-activating connection 'bgu_extern' (1c30c1ba-07ad-4ce6-8126-80740db3234a)
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8708] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'bgu_extern' (1c30c1ba-07ad-4ce6-8126-80740db3234a)
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8710] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8714] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTING
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8719] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8722] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) connection 'bgu_extern' requires no security.  No secrets needed.
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8723] Config: added 'ssid' value 'bgu_extern'
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8723] Config: added 'scan_ssid' value '1'
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8723] Config: added 'bgscan' value 'simple:30:-65:300'
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8723] Config: added 'key_mgmt' value 'NONE'
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8963] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> scanning
Sep 04 14:45:48 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759548.8964] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: ready -> scanning
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.2892] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.2893] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: scanning -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3047] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3047] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3178] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3179] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) Stage 2 of 5 (Device Configure) successful. Connected to wireless network >
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3179] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3193] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> ip-config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.3198] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option dhcp_lease_time      => '86400'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option domain_name_servers  => '192.168.176.1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option expiry               => '1630845952'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option ip_address           => '192.168.183.188'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_broadcast_address => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_name => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4203] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_name_servers => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_domain_search => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_host_name  => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_interface_mtu => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_ms_classless_static_routes => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_nis_domain => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_nis_servers => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_ntp_servers => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_root_path  => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_routers    => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_static_routes => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4204] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_subnet_mask => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_time_offset => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option requested_wpad       => '1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option routers              => '192.168.176.1'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): option subnet_mask          => '255.255.240.0'
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4205] dhcp4 (wlp2s0): state changed unknown -> bound
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4238] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-config -> ip-check (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4937] device (wlp2s0): state change: ip-check -> secondaries (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4943] device (wlp2s0): state change: secondaries -> activated (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.4968] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_LOCAL
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.5010] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_SITE
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.5011] policy: set 'bgu_extern' (wlp2s0) as default for IPv4 routing and DNS
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.5082] device (wlp2s0): Activation: successful, device activated.
Sep 04 14:45:52 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759552.9162] manager: NetworkManager state is now CONNECTED_GLOBAL
Sep 04 14:45:56 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759556.9897] agent-manager: agent[e48d614f8d543379,:1.133/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.4863] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.4864] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.4928] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.4928] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.5151] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 04 14:46:07 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759567.5192] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.8920] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.8921] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: completed -> authenticating
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.9204] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.9251] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: authenticating -> associating
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.9296] device (wlp2s0): supplicant interface state: associating -> completed
Sep 04 14:46:38 castle NetworkManager[1031]: <info>  [1630759598.9318] device (p2p-dev-wlp2s0): supplicant management interface state: associating -> completed
```

And also the output of `nmcli device wifi list`:

```
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID             MODE   CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
*       xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:D2  bgu_extern       Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  48      ▂▄__  --               
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:D0  --               Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  47      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:D6  --               Infra  1     195 Mbit/s  42      ▂▄__  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:C0  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  12      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:A6  --               Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:A2  bgu_extern       Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  --               
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:C6  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:C5  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  WPA2             
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:C2  bgu_extern       Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  10      ▂___  --               
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:A0  --               Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:50  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:56  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  9       ▂___  WPA1 WPA2 802.1X 
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:A5  --               Infra  6     195 Mbit/s  7       ▂___  WPA2             
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:55  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  7       ▂___  WPA2             
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:E5  --               Infra  11    195 Mbit/s  7       ▂___  WPA2             
        xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:FA  1und1 WLAN-DDFA  Infra  1     65 Mbit/s   5       ____  WPA2
```

Comment: have problems connecting to newer wifi standards. What does this mean?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.

Comment: Hi @David, since the problem only appeared this year with newer routers, I concluded that it might have something to do with newer wifi standards

Comment: There has not been any new wifi stands for quite a few years.

Comment: yeah my bad. I thought with upcoming wifi 6 this could have been some reason for the unstable behavior.... I've added the output of the logs related to the netwotk manager from start-up to the point where it first lost connection, @waltinator

Comment: @David 802.11ac was released in 2016; 802.11ax, aka Wi-Fi6, was approved on February 9, 2021. I’d agree that there *have* been recent improvements.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `nmcli device wifi list` Please redact the MAC addresses like this: xxx  GBR5   Infra  149   405 Mbit/s  74      ▂▄▆_  WPA2   Also, is the performance improved if you connect to the 5 gHz band?

Comment: @chili555 please provide reference the ones I read say it was approved over 3 years ago. A mute point just for my interest.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_6 However, ax routers are just now becoming more commonplace. @David

Comment: OK I go by IEEE as I am a member not a wiki but thanks.

Comment: I just added the output of the wifi devices, @chili555. I am not sure if I can manage 5GHz band

Answer (score 2):

We see that you are connected to the access point *bgu_extern* and that there are three instances within scan range. I suggest that you try binding to the strongest of the three like this:  [Ubuntu connect drops. Worked for a while then started dropping again](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425583/ubuntu-connect-drops-worked-for-a-while-then-started-dropping-again/425617#425617)

Comment: thx, good idea. Binding the network card to an access point improves it but does not solve the issue entirely =(